# What is the correct way in JS? Redrawing element or hiding / showing upon filtering?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm working on a project involving data in JSON (later it will be stored in SQL DB) and visualizing it in a dynamic HTML table. Right now I'm reading through the JSON using javascript and create the table accoring to that. After that, while filtering, I'm hiding/showing the involved rows. Would it be a more clean solution to re-read the JSON and re-draw the table using the current filter conditions or using hide/show is a better solution?

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think hide/show may be good for performance that you don't need to refetch the same data from DB everytime you make filter and change the conditions then return to the first one.also refetching data may not be good if your data is huge so your system will be slower. 
So from the perspective of system performance I think hide/show is better.